# How to fix git pull failed "fatal: index-pack failed"

Tags: git

I'm facing a git problem. When I enter `git pull` in Terminal, it loaded for a long time and failed. I use `git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000` but it didn't work.

```
remote: Counting objects: 15205, done.
Receiving objects: 100% (15205/15205), 23.57 MiB | 66.00 KiB/s, done.
fatal: pack is corrupted (SHA1 mismatch)
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I know there's a large size file in remote server. But i dont know how to resolve.

Comment: @lee-pai-long ya, same issure.